# Give an example of a Turing Machine that accepts, but doesn't recognize the language $A=\{ 0, 11 \} \subseteq \{0,1\}*$

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I'm not sure what "accepts, but doesn't recognize" mean. Does it mean it's not supposed to work with that language, but still accepts?

I also don't understand the notation. What does $A=\{ 0, 11 \} \subseteq \{0,1\}*$ mean? That A is all the possible combinations of 0 and 11?

How do I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~rpeng/CS4510_F18/Nov12Reductions.pdf](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/%7Erpeng/CS4510_F18/Nov12Reductions.pdf):

"Recall that a language L is Turing recognizable if there is a Turing machine that accepts exactly the words in L, but can either reject or loop indefinitely on an input that’s not in L."

So just construct a TM that accepts 0, 11, and some other string, but rejects everything else.

{0, 11} is a subset of {0,1}* because {0,1}* means the set of all 0-1 strings.

Comment: But what does recognize mean exactly?

Comment: it seems like from that definition, a language L is recognized by turing machine TM iff TM accepts all words in L and rejects/inf loop on all words not in L

Comment: by accepting too many strings. if my TM accepts 0, 1, 11, 111, 1111, .... then obviously I accept A (as given above) but I fail to recognize A because I dont properly reject (or inf loop) on the strings not in A

Comment: I see. In that case it should accept 0, 11, and some other string, but not reject other inputs, right? So it accepts, but doesn't recognize.

Comment: what is an "invalid input"?

Comment: Anything not in A, ie strings that don't start with 011

Comment: on second thought, you can simply have it accept all strings, that would probably be easier